# How to validate two dates at a time

Tags: laravel, octobercms

In backend create form I need to validate two fields (dates) at a time because I will be checking if some value is BETWEEN these two dates.

I'm stuck at this:

in model I wrote:

```
public $rules = [
    'date_in' => 'checkDate',
    'date_out' => 'checkDate',
];
```

And in Plugin file I wrote:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('checkDate', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
                // I need here two dates
                // a rough condition example: $someValue BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2
                if (condition) return false;
        });

        Validator::replacer('checkDate', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return "My error message";
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Omg, hours searching and thinking and I solved!

`boot()` function in Plugin.php isn't needed. I used only `beforeSave` function for this goal. It's in model:

```
use Db;
use \October\Rain\Exception\ValidationException;
class myModel extends Model
{
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        // I can access dates like that!
        $start = $this->date_in;
        $end = $this->date_out;

        $check = Db::table('mytable')
            ->whereBetween('myColumn', [$start, $end])
            ->get();

        if ($check->count() > 0)
            throw new ValidationException(['date_in' => 'My error message.']);
    }
}
```